# What is difference between Mantra & Shloka

Tags: mantras, shloka

Verses in Vedas are called Mantras where as verses in Gita are called Shlokas.

Can anyone please explain what is difference betwee **Mantra** and **Shloka** ?

Is there some different way to observe them in respect to meaning & chanting?

Comment: Although that is same question as above but accept or upvoted answer seems contradictory to many known facts

Comment: then u can post ur answer there...

Comment: I am not sure with answer myself, upvoted accepted answer for defining Mantra. Although difference is still not sure

Comment: Is there a restriction in calling verses in Vedas as Shlokas? Pls share.